# How to type several equations with one vertical line next to them

Tags: equations

How can I type the following equation in LaTex:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equations can be put in environment `array`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|l@{}}
    2A + 2B = 0\\
    A - B = 1,
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or with ensuring `\displaystyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|>{\displaystyle}l@{}}
    2A + 2B = 0\\
    A - B = 1,
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

or a better line spacing provides `gathered` from package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|l@{}}
  \begin{gathered}
    2A + 2B = 0\\
    A - B = 1,\\
    \sum_{i=0}^{A} = B\\
    \int_{0}^{A} x\,\mathrm{d}x = B
  \end{gathered}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result gathered]

Answer (score 6):

We go colorful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{highlight math style={enhanced,
  colframe=red!60!black,colback=yellow!50!white,arc=4pt,boxrule=1pt,
  drop fuzzy shadow}}

\newtcbox{\otherbox}[1][]{nobeforeafter,math upper,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,
  enhanced,colframe=red!60!black,boxrule=0pt,leftrule=1pt,left=0pt,interior style={top color=green!10!white,
  bottom color=green!10!white,middle color=green!50!yellow},
  fuzzy halo=1pt with green,#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box={\tcbhighmath[colback=blue!20!white,boxrule=0pt,leftrule=1pt,left=0pt,arc=0pt]}]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[box=\otherbox]{align}
a&=b\\
E&=mc^2 + \int_a^a x\, dx
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the environment `empheq` from the [`empheq`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
  \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlvert\;\;]{align*}
    &2A + 2B = 0\\
    &A - B = 1,
  \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Once more, there was a post with the same idea before I had finished testing mine, and I didn't check before posting myself!

Comment: @Bernard It often happens to me, too... :-)

Answer (score 3):

With the `empheq` package (providing the `overload` option) there is a much simpler solution: you can put about anything you please on the left or on the right of an `amsmath` environment. Please note that `empheq` loads  `mathtools` that in turn loads `amsmath` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}[left=\color{Purple}\empheqlbrace\enspace, right=quad\color{red} \empheqlVert]%
2A + 2B = 0\\
A - B = 1,\\
\sum_{i=0}^{A} = B\\
\int_{0}^{A} x\,\mathrm{d}x = B
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]